# Is there an UEFI with NVRAM entries editor

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, uefi

As topic states - is anyone aware of an UEFI (incorrectly still called BIOS) for a modern motherboard which provides NVRAM boot entries editor?

The question is **not** about "how can I edit those entries" — I am aware of the [alternatives](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html), rather (my prime question) was "which motherboard manufacturer provides UEFI with *advanced/good features*. Unfortunately *good* is a subjective term so I figured I'll ask for a specific feature which is good enough for me and if the UEFI has that feature, then there's a good chance the UEFI is "advanced enough".

NB: Editing NVRAM from within the Operating System leaves much to be desired as often those entries magically disappear, are not persistent or not detectable at all. [Matthew Garret](https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/20187.html)'s blog even says about some UEFIs that will not show boot entries that do not match specific strings, ie  `Windows Boot Manager` or `Fedora Linux`
.